# shows blanks for repeating values in a result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In the query below, for  o.EventSetName, o.EventSetDisplay, o.EventSetDescription - any time the 3 columns in the result have duplicate ROWS - only the first such row should be shown and blank for the rest of the duplicate rows.....

here is the sql:

```
 Select  distinct top 100000 o.EventSetName,       
                             o.EventSetDisplay,
                             o.EventSetDescription,
                             o.ChildSetName,
                             ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By f.ChildSetName) RN,
                             f.DocumentDispSequence,
                             f.SectionDispSequence,
                             o.ObsSetDispSequence,
                             null                          
                      From   ##ObsSetLevel o,
                             ##Final f
                      Where  f.ChildSetName = o.EventSetName and 
                             o.EventSetName = @variableName
                      Order By RN asc, f.DocumentDispSequence asc, f.SectionDispSequence asc, o.ObsSetDispSequence asc
```

I dont have a reporting tool so for now a lot of the reporting logic needs to be done in the stored proc itself...

So instead of:

```
val 1   val2    val3  val7
val 1   val2    val3  val8
val 1   val2    val3  val 10
val 1   val2    val3  x
val 1   val2    val3  y
```

I should get the resullt with blanks for the first 3 columns for rows 2,3,4 and 5

Comment: When you have 1st row val1, val2, val3, ...; 2nd row val4, val2, val5, ...; 3rd row val1, val2, val3, ...; what do you want to show blank? Do notice that you are not ordering by the columns on which you want to operate, which means that for each row you analyze you will have to check every previous row, and also that you can't guarantee the same results each time

Comment: val 1, val2 and val3 - should be blank for ROWS 2, 3, 4 and 5 - instead of being displayed again. The Ordering really has to happen via the display sequence...the first three columns (o.EventSetName, o.EventSetDisplay, o.EventSetDescription, which I call val 1, val2 and val3 in my example are guaranteed to all be all located in successive rows (thats I I am grouping elsewhere in the stored procedure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your existing query in CTE adding `ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION BY` your columns, which will create RNs for each group of values. In outer query just use CASE to select values where GRP_RN = 1 and empty string otherwise.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    Select  distinct top 100000 
        o.EventSetName,       
        o.EventSetDisplay,
        o.EventSetDescription,
        o.ChildSetName,
        ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By f.ChildSetName) RN,
        f.DocumentDispSequence,
        f.SectionDispSequence,
        o.ObsSetDispSequence,
        null  as NullColumnNeedsName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.EventSetName, o.EventSetDisplay,o.EventSetDescription ORDER BY f.ChildSetName) GRP_RN
    From   ##ObsSetLevel o,
    INNER JOIN ##Final f ON f.ChildSetName = o.EventSetName and o.EventSetName = @variableName
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN GRP_RN = 1 THEN o.EventSetName ELSE '' END AS EventSetName,
    CASE WHEN GRP_RN = 1 THEN o.EventSetDisplay ELSE '' END AS EventSetDisplay,
    CASE WHEN GRP_RN = 1 THEN o.EventSetDescription ELSE '' END AS EventSetDescription,
    other columns
FROM CTE  
Order By RN asc, DocumentDispSequence asc, SectionDispSequence asc, o.ObsSetDispSequence asc
```

PS: I have also corrected your use of old-style joins. That usage is outdated more than 20 years ago with introduction of SQL-92 standards. [You should avoid using them.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)