# Sql Query to get total of different "StatusName" column, based on year ("CreatedDate" column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following need:

When I join 2 tables, I get records as below:
[image]

Below is the query I am using to get above result:

```
Select R.[StatusCode] , RS.[StatusName], R.[CreatedDate]

FROM Table1 as R
Inner Join Table2 as RS
ON R.StatusCode=RS.StatusName

order by R.CreatedDate;
```

**My requirement is:** I want to count the total of different-different `StatusName` for every year (based on `CreatedDate`).

**i.e.,** year 2012 got-

3 -- records for "Complete" StatusName
1 -- records for "void" StatusName
2 -- records for "Match" StatusName

year 2013 got-

2 -- records for "Cancel" StatusName
3 -- records for "IPR" StatusName
2 -- records for "Void" StatusName

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Later I have to import the expected data into Excel. Can any body help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
Select RS.[StatusName], DATEPART ( datepart , R.[CreatedDate] ) as Y, COUNT(RS.[StatusName]) As Total
FROM Table1 as R
Inner Join Table2 as RS
ON R.StatusCode=RS.StatusName
GROUP BY DATEPART ( datepart , R.[CreatedDate] )
```

If you dont want the year to be repeated Wrap your existing query in CTE adding ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION BY your columns, which will create RNs for each group of values. In outer query just use CASE to select values where GRP_RN = 1 and empty string otherwise.

Look at this for your reference if you need that part:

[shows blanks for repeating values in a result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767504/shows-blanks-for-repeating-values-in-a-result-set)

Comment: Thank you for the help Aram, In my side query, `GROUP BY` clause was not correct. Your suggested code helped me to look into my side error. Now working fine. Last thing I want to know that how to calculate the `GrandTotal` for `Total` column in same query ? Please reply

Comment: You can use WITH ROLLUP command for that. Add it to the end of the query

Comment: Thank you for the reply Aram, When I add `WITH ROLLUP` command at the end of query, I get few records as `NULL`. Please reply

Comment: Yes, it rolls up for all colums, you can get rid of them with some additional where clauses if you dont need them

Comment: Remember to mark as answer if it fixes your issue please. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot for the help.