# SQL limit join to the first dataset

Tags: sql, left-join

I have lots of datasets of genomic ranges. I am trying to associate overlapping genomic ranges from each dataset. I have a master list of genomic ranges that includes everything in the dataset. I want to associate each dataset back to that master list, however if there is more than one range that overlaps I don't want it to increase the number of rows in the master list, I want that database to be able to just hold a variable number of rows in each dataset that is associated with the master list. This is to avoid this problem, assuming each of these is a genomic range:

```
R1       R2       R5
R1       R2       R6
R1       R2       R7
R1       R3       R5
R1       R3       R6
R1       R3       R7
R1       R4       R5
R1       R4       R6
R1       R4       R7
```

Instead I would want it to look like this, where R1 is the 'master index':

```
R1       R2       R5
         R3       R6
         R4       R7
```

Currently all I can produce with SQL is the first situation that I am trying to avoid. Here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    S2.chrom, 
    S2.ChromStart, 
    S2.ChromEnd, 
    S2.width,
    S2_1ug.S2_1ug.ChromStart AS S2_1ug_ChromStart, 
    S2_1ug.S2_1ug.ChromEnd AS S2_1ug_ChromEnd,
    S2_5ug.s2_5ug.ChromStart AS S2_5ug_ChromStart, 
    S2_5ug.S2_5ug.ChromEnd AS S2_5ug_ChromEnd,
    s2_1ug.ChromStart AS s2_1ug_ChromStart, 
    s2_1ug.ChromEnd AS s2_1ug_ChromEnd,
    s2_5ug.ChromStart AS s2_5ug_ChromStart, 
    s2_5ug.ChromEnd AS s2_5ug_ChromEnd,


FROM S2.S2
LEFT JOIN S2_1ug.S2_1ug ON 
    S2.chrom = S2_1ug.chrom
    AND ((S2.ChromStart BETWEEN S2_1ug.ChromStart AND S2_1ug.ChromEnd) OR (S2.ChromEnd BETWEEN S2_1ug.ChromStart AND S2_1ug.ChromEnd))
LEFT JOIN S2_1ug.s2_1ug ON 
    S2.chrom = s2_1ug.chrom
    AND ((S2.ChromStart BETWEEN s2_1ug.ChromStart AND s2_1ug.ChromEnd) OR (S2.ChromEnd BETWEEN s2_1ug.ChromStart AND s2_1ug.ChromEnd))
LEFT JOIN S2_5ug.S2_5ug ON 
    S2.chrom = S2_5ug.chrom
    AND ((S2.ChromStart BETWEEN S2_5ug.ChromStart AND S2_5ug.ChromEnd) OR (S2.ChromEnd BETWEEN S2_5ug.ChromStart AND S2_5ug.ChromEnd))
LEFT JOIN S2_5ug.s2_5ug ON 
    S2.chrom = s2_5ug.chrom
    AND ((S2.ChromStart BETWEEN s2_5ug.ChromStart AND s2_5ug.ChromEnd) OR (S2.ChromEnd BETWEEN s2_5ug.ChromStart AND s2_5ug.ChromEnd));
```

Where S2 would be the 'master index'.

Here are example datasets:

S2 master index:

```
chr2L       850264       850894
chr2L       1076737       1077723
```

S2_1ug

```
chr2L       850635       850883
chr2L       1076875       1077423
chr2L       1077575       1077723
```

S2_5ug

```
chr2L       850635       850883
chr2L       1076875       1077023
chr2L       1077225       1077373
```

s2_1ug

```
chr2L       850264       850845
chr2L       1076737       1077674
```

s2_5ug

```
chr2L       850264       850845
chr2L       1076738       1077699
```

And it comes out looking like this:

```
chr2L       850264       850894 chr2L       850635       850883 chr2L       850635       850883 chr2L       850264       850845
chr2L       1076737       1077723   chr2L       1076875       1077423   chr2L       1076875       1077023   chr2L       1076737       1077674
chr2L       1076737       1077723   chr2L       1076875       1077423   chr2L       1077225       1077373   chr2L       1076737       1077674
chr2L       1076737       1077723   chr2L       1077575       1077723   chr2L       1076875       1077023   chr2L       1076737       1077674
chr2L       1076737       1077723   chr2L       1077575       1077723   chr2L       1077225       1077373   chr2L       1076737       1077674
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
chr2L       850264       850894     chr2L       850635       850883     chr2L       850635       850883     chr2L       850264       850845     chr2L       850264       850845
chr2L       1076737       1077723   chr2L       1076875       1077423   chr2L       1076875       1077023   chr2L       1076737       1077674   chr2L       1076738       1077699
                                    chr2L       1077575       1077723   chr2L       1077225       1077373
```

Basically so that the first master dataset is acting as the index for the rest of the data, which is allowed to vary in row number in relation to the master dataset. Any ideas?

Comment: Blanking out subrows that are the same as preceding subrows under some ordering is a faq. (Also the sort of presentation manipulation typically best done in a GUI not a DB.) But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably. This post contains no such phrasing(s).

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: `chr2L       850635       850883` from `S2_1ug` should not be in your result set because it doesn't satisfy the condition `((S2.ChromStart BETWEEN S2_1ug.ChromStart AND S2_1ug.ChromEnd) OR (S2.ChromEnd BETWEEN S2_1ug.ChromStart AND S2_1ug.ChromEnd))`

Comment: Googling 'site:stackoverflow.com sql replace duplicate values in a column by blank OR null' ... [shows blanks for repeating values in a result set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18767504/3404097) (Etc) PS Such display-oriented transformations are generally better done in a presentation layer.

Comment: Please update your question. It is quite unclear like this. Tags are sql and left-join but there is  no rdbms you use. You ask for sql code, but there is no table names, column names, datatypes,...The logic is also unclear without the data definition... Question looks interresting, though. I'm afraid if you don't update there will be  no adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the dataset given,

```
create table S2(chrom varchar,ChromStart numeric,ChromEnd numeric);
create table S2_1ug(chrom varchar,ChromStart numeric,ChromEnd numeric);
create table S2_5ug(chrom varchar,ChromStart numeric,ChromEnd numeric);
create table s2_11ug(chrom varchar,ChromStart numeric,ChromEnd numeric);
create table s2_55ug(chrom varchar,ChromStart numeric,ChromEnd numeric);

insert into S2 values ('chr2L',850264,850894),('chr2L',1076737,1077723);
insert into S2_1ug values ('chr2L',850635,850883),('chr2L',1076875,1077423),('chr2L',1077575,1077723);
insert into S2_5ug values ('chr2L',850635,850883),('chr2L',1076875,1077023),('chr2L',1077225,1077373);
insert into s2_11ug values ('chr2L',850264,850845),('chr2L',1076737,1077674);
insert into s2_55ug values ('chr2L',850264,850845),('chr2L',1076738,1077699);
```

Below SQL will create the output removing the duplication.

```
SELECT  
    S2.chrom, 
    S2.ChromStart, 
    S2.ChromEnd,
    S2_1ug.S2_1ug_ChromStart,
    S2_1ug.S2_1ug_ChromEnd,
    S2_5ug.S2_5ug_ChromStart,
    S2_5ug.S2_5ug_ChromEnd,
    s2_11ug.S2_11ug_ChromStart,
    s2_11ug.S2_11ug_ChromEnd,
    s2_55ug.S2_55ug_ChromStart,
    s2_55ug.S2_55ug_ChromEnd   
    
FROM 
(
    select S2.chrom,S2.ChromStart,S2.ChromEnd,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S2.chrom ORDER BY S2.ChromStart,S2.ChromEnd) as row_no
    from S2
)S2
full outer join 
(
    select S2_1ug.ChromStart AS S2_1ug_ChromStart,S2_1ug.ChromEnd AS S2_1ug_ChromEnd,S2_1ug.chrom,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S2_1ug.chrom ORDER BY S2_1ug.ChromStart,S2_1ug.ChromEnd) as row_no
    from S2_1ug
)S2_1ug on S2_1ug.row_no=S2.row_no
full outer join 
(
    select s2_11ug.ChromStart AS S2_11ug_ChromStart,s2_11ug.ChromEnd AS S2_11ug_ChromEnd,s2_11ug.chrom,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s2_11ug.chrom ORDER BY s2_11ug.ChromStart,s2_11ug.ChromEnd) as row_no
    from s2_11ug
)s2_11ug on s2_11ug.row_no=S2.row_no
full outer join 
(
    select S2_5ug.ChromStart AS S2_5ug_ChromStart,S2_5ug.ChromEnd AS S2_5ug_ChromEnd,S2_5ug.chrom,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S2_5ug.chrom ORDER BY S2_5ug.ChromStart,S2_5ug.ChromEnd) as row_no
    from S2_5ug
)S2_5ug on S2_5ug.row_no=S2.row_no
full outer join 
(
    select s2_55ug.ChromStart AS s2_55ug_ChromStart,s2_55ug.ChromEnd AS s2_55ug_ChromEnd,s2_55ug.chrom,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s2_55ug.chrom ORDER BY s2_55ug.ChromStart,s2_55ug.ChromEnd) as row_no
    from s2_55ug
)s2_55ug on s2_55ug.row_no=S2.row_no
;
```

Output:

```
chrom | chromstart | chromend | s2_1ug_chromstart | s2_1ug_chromend | s2_5ug_chromstart | s2_5ug_chromend | s2_11ug_chromstart | s2_11ug_chromend | s2_55ug_chromstart | s2_55ug_chromend 
-------+------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+------------------
 chr2L |     850264 |   850894 |            850635 |          850883 |            850635 |          850883 |             850264 |           850845 |             850264 |           850845
 chr2L |    1076737 |  1077723 |           1076875 |         1077423 |           1076875 |         1077023 |            1076737 |          1077674 |            1076738 |          1077699
       |            |          |           1077575 |         1077723 |                   |                 |                    |                  |                    |                 
       |            |          |                   |                 |           1077225 |         1077373 |                    |                  |                    |
```

Answer (score 0):

With the data provided...

```sql
WITH  s2  (CHROM, CHROM_START, CHROM_END) AS
          ( Select 'chr2L',  850264,  850894 From Dual Union All
            Select 'chr2L', 1076737, 1077723 From Dual 
          ),
    s2_1ug (CHROM, CHROM_START, CHROM_END) AS
          ( Select 'chr2L',  850635,  850883 From Dual Union All
            Select 'chr2L', 1076875, 1077423 From Dual Union All
            Select 'chr2L', 1077575, 1077723 From Dual 
          ),
    s2_5ug (CHROM, CHROM_START, CHROM_END) AS
          ( Select 'chr2L',  850635,  850883 From Dual Union All
            Select 'chr2L', 1076875, 1077023 From Dual Union All
            Select 'chr2L', 1077225, 1077373 From Dual 
          ),
    s2_11ug (CHROM, CHROM_START, CHROM_END) AS
          ( Select 'chr2L',  850264,  850845 From Dual Union All
            Select 'chr2L', 1076737, 1077674 From Dual 
          ),
    s2_55ug (CHROM, CHROM_START, CHROM_END) AS
          ( Select 'chr2L',  850264,  850845 From Dual Union All
            Select 'chr2L', 1076738, 1077699 From Dual 
          ),
```

.. since you mentioned more "datasets" - you could consider collecting them all in one cte (named it  all_data) adding RN (row number within the source) and the SOURCE dataset info ...

```sql
    all_data (RN, SOURCE, CHROM, CHROM_START, CHROM_END) AS
          ( Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By s.CHROM Order By s.CHROM_START), 's2', s.* From s2 s Union All
            Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By s.CHROM Order By s.CHROM_START), 's2_1ug', s.* From s2_1ug  s Union All
            Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By s.CHROM Order By s.CHROM_START), 's2_11ug', s.* From s2_11ug s Union All
            Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By s.CHROM Order By s.CHROM_START), 's2_5ug', s.* From s2_5ug s Union All
            Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By s.CHROM Order By s.CHROM_START), 's2_55ug', s.* From s2_55ug s 
            -- the same way you could add the rest of your datasets here
          )
```

The rows collected could be PIVOT-ed into columns:

```sql
Select  CASE WHEN Max(CHROM_START) Is Not Null THEN CHROM END "Chrom", Max(CHROM_START) "ChromStart", Max(CHROM_END) "ChromEnd",
        --
        CASE WHEN Max(S2_1UG_CHROM_START) Is Not Null THEN CHROM END "s2_1ug_Chrom", Max(S2_1UG_CHROM_START) "s2_1ug_ChromStart", Max(S2_1UG_CHROM_END) "s2_1ug_ChromEnd",
        --
        CASE WHEN Max(S2_5UG_CHROM_START) Is Not Null THEN CHROM END "s2_5ug_Chrom", Max(S2_5UG_CHROM_START) "s2_5ug_ChromStart", Max(S2_5UG_CHROM_END) "s2_5ug_ChromEnd",
        --
        CASE WHEN Max(S2_11UG_CHROM_START) Is Not Null THEN CHROM END "s2_11ug_Chrom", Max(S2_11UG_CHROM_START) "s2_11ug_ChromStart", Max(S2_11UG_CHROM_END) "s2_11ug_ChromEnd",
        --
        CASE WHEN Max(S2_55UG_CHROM_START) Is Not Null THEN CHROM END "s2_55ug_Chrom", Max(S2_55UG_CHROM_START) "s2_55ug_ChromStart", Max(S2_55UG_CHROM_END) "s2_55ug_ChromEnd"
        --  other dataset's aggregations could be added here
From (  Select    *
        From   (  Select * From all_data ) 
            PIVOT( Max(CHROM_START) "START", MAX(CHROM_END)  "END"
                   FOR SOURCE IN('s2' "CHROM", 's2_1ug' "S2_1UG_CHROM", 's2_5ug' "S2_5UG_CHROM", 's2_11ug' "S2_11UG_CHROM", 's2_55ug' "S2_55UG_CHROM")  ) 
                              -- widen IN elements with the rest of sources
     )
Group By RN, CHROM
Order By RN, CHROM
```

Resulting as asked for:

| Chrom | ChromStart | ChromEnd | s2_1ug_Chrom | s2_1ug_ChromStart | s2_1ug_ChromEnd | s2_5ug_Chrom | s2_5ug_ChromStart | s2_5ug_ChromEnd | s2_11ug_Chrom | s2_11ug_ChromStart | s2_11ug_ChromEnd | s2_55ug_Chrom | s2_55ug_ChromStart | s2_55ug_ChromEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr2L | 850264 | 850894 | chr2L | 850635 | 850883 | chr2L | 850635 | 850883 | chr2L | 850264 | 850845 | chr2L | 850264 | 850845 |
| chr2L | 1076737 | 1077723 | chr2L | 1076875 | 1077423 | chr2L | 1076875 | 1077023 | chr2L | 1076737 | 1077674 | chr2L | 1076738 | 1077699 |
|  |  |  | chr2L | 1077575 | 1077723 | chr2L | 1077225 | 1077373 |  |  |  |  |  |  |